# Removing select N+1 without .Include

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Consider these contrived entity objects:

```
public class Consumer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool NeedsProcessed { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }  //virtual so EF can lazy-load
}

public class Purchase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalCost { get; set; }
    public int ConsumerId { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's say I want to run this code:

```
var consumers = Consumers.Where(consumer => consumer.NeedsProcessed);

//assume that ProcessConsumers accesses the Consumer.Purchases property
SomeExternalServiceICannotModify.ProcessConsumers(consumers);
```

By default this will suffer from Select N+1 inside the ProcessConsumers method.  It will trigger a query when it enumerates the consumers, then it'll grab each purchases collection 1 by 1.  The standard solution to this problem would be to add an include:

```
var consumers = Consumers.Include("Purchases").Where(consumer => consumer.NeedsProcessed);

//assume that ProcessConsumers accesses the Consumer.Purchases property
SomeExternalServiceICannotModify.ProcessConsumers(consumers);
```

That works fine in many cases, but in some complex cases, an include can utterly destroy performance by orders of magnitude.  Is it possible to do something like this:

1. Grab my consumers, var consumers = _entityContext.Consumers.Where(...).ToList()
2. Grab my purchases, var purchases = _entityContext.Purchases.Where(...).ToList()
3. Hydrate the consumer.Purchases collections manually from the purchases I already loaded into memory.  Then when I pass it to ProcessConsumers it won't trigger more db queries.

I'm not sure how to do #3.  If you try to access any consumer.Purchases collection that'll trigger the lazy load (and thus the Select N+1).  Perhaps I need to cast the Consumers to the proper type (instead of the EF proxy type) and then load the collection?  Something like this:

```
foreach (var consumer in Consumers)
{
     //since the EF proxy overrides the Purchases property, this doesn't really work, I'm trying to figure out what would
     ((Consumer)consumer).Purchases = purchases.Where(x => x.ConsumerId = consumer.ConsumerId).ToList();
}
```

**EDIT:**
I have re-written the example a bit to hopefully reveal the issue more clearly.

Comment: IIRC EF will automatically hydrate the collections, so #3 does not have to be done manually.

Comment: Your first query should execute as a single SQL statement. Are you seeing multiple db calls?

Comment: @Nicholas, you're right, I updated the example to make it Select N+1.  This is a very simple contrived example, read the whole question and try to understand what I'm really asking.  Actual examples where .Include is insufficient are dramatically more complex and not reasonable to put inside a SO question.

Comment: You should definitely remove the .ToList() call on your first query, as that will cause it to execute against the database before the next line is executed.

Comment: @Kris You're wrong, the .ToList() called on the first query prevent to re-execute it again, becuase the list is loaded in memory.

Comment: @Kris, yes I could remove the ToList() but this is just an example to try to give some context to my question.  Please focus on the question (manually overwrite the built-in EF hydration), not on how you could re-write my overly-simplified example.

Comment: @Fuex Like I said, with .ToList() the first line will execute a query against the database. Without .ToList(), it will not. Again without .ToList(), only the second line will execute a query against the database. There is never any need to execute a second query, unless there is a first one.

Comment: @manu08 I understand what you're saying, but your exeample is not a good illustration of your real problem. Your real problem is how to have linq to entities create efficient queries. Unfortunately, it is not very good at that. But you can help! The first trick is to never query for data you don't need. So, if you only need one or two columns, only select those one or two columns, not an entire entity. In fact, always avoid selecting entire entities, unless you need to update them. And if you want just a sum, query for just a sum. So again, don't do the .ToList() call.

Comment: @Fuex.  I mean populate the properties.  For example, calling consumer.Purchases will cause the EF proxy object to perform a db query to grab the purchase data and then hydrate the property.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you would like to load both a filtered subset of Consumers each with a filtered subset of their Purchases in 1 query. If that's not correct, please forgive my understanding of your intent. If that is correct, you could do something like:

```
var consumersAndPurchases = db.Consumers.Where(...)
    .Select(c => new {
        Consumer = c,
        RelevantPurchases = c.Purchases.Where(...)
    })
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToList(); // loads in 1 query

// this should be OK because we did AsNoTracking()
consumersAndPurchases.ForEach(t => t.Consumer.Purchases = t.RelevantPurchases);

CannotModify.Process(consumersAndPurchases.Select(t => t.Consumer));
```

Note that this WON'T work if the Process function is expecting to modify the consumer object and then commit those changes back to the database.

Comment: This will prevent change tracking, but I believe t.Consumer.Purchases will still trigger a lazy load, before saving t.RelevantPurchases over it.

Comment: I'm surprised that that would happen. However, if that is happening, you could add (after the ToList() call): .Select(t => new Consumer { /* copy all relevant fields from t.Consumer */, Purchases = t.RelevantPurchases }).ToList(). That should effectively map everything into non-EF-proxy objects which shouldn't do any lazy loading. Another option is to make the Purchases property non-virtual, although this will also prevent lazy-loading elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

EF will populate the `consumer.Purchases` collections for you, if you use the same context to fetch both collections:

```
List<Consumer> consumers = null;
using ( var ctx = new XXXEntities() )
{
  consumers = ctx.Consumers.Where( ... ).ToList();

  // EF will populate consumers.Purchases when it loads these objects
  ctx.Purchases.Where( ... ).ToList();
}

// the Purchase objects are now in the consumer.Purchases collections
var sum = consumers.Sum( c => c.Purchases.Sum( p => p.TotalCost ) );
```

**EDIT :**

This results in just 2 db calls: 1 to get the collection of `Consumers` and 1 to get the collection of `Purchases`.

EF will look at each `Purchase` record returned and look up the corresponding `Consumer` record from `Purchase.ConsumerId`. It will then add the `Purchase` object to the `Consumer.Purchases` collection for you.

---

Option 2:

If there is some reason you want to fetch two lists from different contexts and then link them, I would add another property to the `Consumer` class:

```
partial class Consumer
{
  public List<Purchase> UI_Purchases { get; set; }
}
```

You can then set this property from the `Purchases` collection and use it in your UI.

Comment: Option 1 is a restatement of what I have above, right?  It'll still have select n+1.  Option 2 is reasonable, but it won't really work for my case.  I'll update my original question to elaborate.

Comment: No, it results in just 2 db calls. I've added more explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> **Grab my consumers**

```
var consumers = _entityContext.Consumers
                              .Where(consumer => consumer.Id > 1000)
                              .ToList();
```

> **Grab my purchases**

```
var purchases = consumers.Select(x => new {
                                       Id = x.Id,
                                       IList<Purchases> Purchases = x.Purchases         
                                       })
                         .ToList()
                         .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                         .Select( x => x.Aggregate((merged, next) => merged.Merge(next)))
                         .ToList();
```

> **Hydrate the consumer.Purchases collections manually from the
>   purchases I already loaded into memory.**

```
for(int i = 0; i < costumers.Lenght; i++)
   costumers[i].Purchases = purchases[i];
```

Comment: I believe the left half of, consumers[i].Purchases = purchases[i], will trigger EF to try to load Purchases for you.  So you'll trigger the lazy load then over-write it.

Comment: You could just detach the object graph from the context, or disable the lazy loading capability, before doing step 3.

Comment: @MortenMertner In my case I cannot fully disable lazy loading because I need other things to be lazy loaded later on.  I will play around with detaching the object, manually loading, then re-attaching the object.  Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @manu08 I'm pretty sure you can just disable lazy-loading temporarily by toggling the `this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled` property inside your DbContext derived class. Assuming that you're not sharing the context across threads this should work fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be possible for you to work around the many-roundtrips-or-inefficient-query-generation problem by doing the work on the database - essentially by returning a projection instead of a particular entity, as demonstrated below:

```
var query = from c in db.Consumers
            where c.Id > 1000
            select new { Consumer = c, Total = c.Purchases.Sum( p => p.TotalCost ) };
var total = query.Sum( cp => cp.Total );
```

I'm not an EF expert by any means, so forgive me if this technique is not appropriate.

Comment: That technique is fine for the contrived example, but I'm asking you to assume it's much more complicated (e.g., you need to do lots of other stuff with Consumers and their Purchases, so you want the whole object graph in memory).

Comment: Assume that my example is equally contrived, in that I just return the Total from the purchases. You could easily return collections of related objects hand-picked for the stuff you need to do. Select the data into a custom projection class (i.e. ConsumerPurchasesForYearlyReportData or some such) and use that as your seed for the following work. ORMs in general (and EF in particular) are not great at returning filtered associations.